# Insane heat development with ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, led, eeprom

I have a ESP8266 on a Wemos D1 mini board. Simple "Rainbow with FastLED" animation. Shouldn't do much but the board gets so hot I can't touch it and it drains a 2500mAh battery in less than an hour.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Especially as a comparable micropython implementation just doesn't get that hot and the same battery keeps for about 5 hrs...

Here's the code

```cpp
#define FASTLED_ALLOW_INTERRUPTS 0
#include "FastLED.h"
#include <EEPROM.h>

// How many leds in your strip?
#define NUM_LEDS 60
#define DATA_PIN 13
#define CLOCK_PIN 14
#define COLOR_ORDER RGB
int starthue = 0;
int incrementer = 255/NUM_LEDS;
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS*2];
int address = 0;
int max_modes = 4;
int colormode; 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  FastLED.addLeds<APA102, DATA_PIN, CLOCK_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS*2);
    EEPROM.begin(512);
  colormode = EEPROM.read(address);
  Serial.println(colormode);
  int new_mode = (colormode == max_modes) ? 1 : ++colormode; 
  Serial.println(new_mode);
  new_mode = (colormode == 0) ? 1: new_mode;
  Serial.println(new_mode);
  EEPROM.write(address, new_mode);
  EEPROM.commit();
  EEPROM.end();
}


void rainbow_mid(int howfast) {
  while (true) { 
    fill_rainbow(leds, NUM_LEDS, starthue, incrementer);
    for (int i =0; i< NUM_LEDS; i++) {
      leds[NUM_LEDS-i-1] = leds[i];
      leds[NUM_LEDS*2-i-1] = leds[i];
    }
    FastLED.show();
    delay(howfast);
    starthue++;
  }
}

void rainbow(int howfast) {
  while (true) { 
    fill_rainbow(leds, NUM_LEDS, starthue, incrementer);
    //addGlitter(80);
    for (int i =0; i< NUM_LEDS; i++) {
      //leds[NUM_LEDS-i-1] = leds[i];
      leds[NUM_LEDS*2-i-1] = leds[i];
    }
    FastLED.show();
    delay(howfast);
    starthue++;
  }

}


void loop() {
  switch(colormode) {
    case 1: rainbow_mid(10); break;
    case 2: rainbow_mid(50); break;
    case 3: rainbow(10); break;
    case 4: rainbow(50); break;
  }

}
```

Comment: Same board, same connections in both cases?

Comment: The problem does not lie in your code, but in the connections. 60 RGB LEDs can draw about 20mA*3*60 = 3.6A (all LEDs in full white). Showing a rainbow will draw less current, but as Tirdad wrote in his answer, that will still be too much for the onboard regulator. How have you connected everything? How have you connected the battery?

Answer (score 1):

the heat is from the supply lines of board.

it's not the chip itself, as if it gets hot like that the chip should be destroyed.
it seems you have connected 60 LEDs strip to the board and you provide it's supply from the board's supply line. so the lines get hot, and the board gets hot too.
so the heat is not from the chip. its from power supply tracks on the PCB.

use another power source for the LED strip.